# I creates an app and tested on simulator as well as device but not going to upload on app store

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a app which uploaded on app store, somehow thats not working so now i want to update new version of that app but when creates archive showing error. I tested this version on simulator as well as on device and its working properly but showing error during uploading to app store. i am posting theses errors
please help me.

> 1. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> 2. Command/Applications/Xcode2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip
>      failed with exit code 1

Comment: shift+Cmd+K to  Clean the project in Xcode and run it again then again same error is there ?

Comment: yes sir i cleaned many times but always showing same error

Comment: Check your certificate and profile.

Comment: All checked.. profile and certificates are valid..

Comment: This is compiler error or Application Loader error ?

Comment: Error comes during uploading.. app running properly in device and simulator

Answer (score 0):

In Project Build settings, please verify your strip settings, type strip on right top search corner and compare the strip options as in attached screenshots.

[image]

Comment: Hello still not getting the solution... please help

Comment: what are the frameworks you are using in the application: frameworks and static library. Can you share the Build Phase detail screenshot

Comment: Not able to attach the screenshots.. its not attaching with my post